# jquery mobile navigate to ID inside page

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

So I'm wondering if there's a way to navigate to a specific id inside the "page" after the page-transition.

Basically, I want to store a variable (ID of element I'm currently at on a page) so that I can return to the same spot on the "page" of a multi-page template that I came from.  I can't just change the href of the anchor, because for the page transition to happen it has to be linked to an ID associated with the data-type="page", and I can't just append my id to the end of this either because it still won't trigger the page transition.

Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store the variable in a session variable or cookie, check the length on page load and trigger a function to return back to the id.

Take a look at [sessvars](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html)